# Bitmap otained is transparent but when set to imageview becomes non-transparent

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm using OpenCV to implement something simple, that if `Mat` has color of pixel(x,y) equal to white, it turns to transparent (alpha = 0). After that convert `Mat` to `bitmap`.

[image]

When debugging the bitmap returned is correct, but when i set it to `imageview`, the image returned still has white background (as in the original image) instead of the transparent image.

This is the original image (with white background)

[image]

And debugging image, with transparent background

[image]

Please help me to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your ImageView,

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: what about ' android:background="@null" '